# 500 internal server error trying to install Shopify app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

This is my app: https://dialective-shopify.herokuapp.com

It gets installed with no problems in `development` mode.

It gets installed in `production` mode **BUT ONLY** if I read a few products from the development shop:

```
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 10})
```

If I try to read 50 products:

```
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 50})
```

and reinstall the app from scratch in the dev shop, then I get a 500 server error:

> A static HTML page can contain a simple dependency free script to set the top bar to a 500 server error. This page can be found in 'public/500.html'.

in the following GET request:

[image]

with header:

[image]

This happens after giving the authorization for installing the app as well as for the TEST payment.

If I refresh the page pressing F5 several times, **eventually the installation process successfully finishes** and the app gets loaded!

I don't even know where to start looking since the error is on the server side (presumably on Shopify's servers) and I can't reproduce it in development mode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 500 error is your problem, not Shopify's. You need to examine your logs in heroku where you'll probably find your problem very quickly in the stack trace provided.

Comment: That's a very good point. I just evaluated my logs (`heroku logs -n 1500`) and there are some interesting clues pointing to where the error may be. And yes, it's probably my fault. Thanks!